# Azure Blob Storage file upload in blocks

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am writing a C# Console Application that uploads Local Files to Azure Blob Storage.

While Uploading Large files(say .pdf files here) I am doing two things

1. Breaking the File into blocks.
2. Using SemphoreSlim while staging blocks on azure Cloud storage.

Is there any way to test the blocks are in the correct sequence as expected and pdf is not corrupted after committing the blocks?

What I tried is reading the file again after upload and validating the signature, but in cases where some pages or some portion of pdf is missing how to detect this kind of issues.

Comment: _"Breaking the File into blocks."_ - **why?** Range-based uploads don't require that at all.

Comment: _"Using SemphoreSlim while staging blocks on azure Cloud storage."_ - **why?** [Azure Blob Storage's Lease and Lock functionality is designed to make it unnecessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/concurrency-manage?tabs=dotnet) for client-side synchronziation in this scenario.

Comment: _"Is there any way to test the blocks are in the correct sequence as expected and pdf is not corrupted after committing the blocks?"_ - ...you wouldn't need to ask this question if you just passed a `FileStream` to the Azure client library and didn't unnecessary complicate things.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written. Also, as mentioned in other comments you don’t really have to manually upload blocks. SDK will take care of this for you.

Comment: what I intended was break large files into blocks
and upload blocks with multiple threads (control threads with semaphoreslim) parallely on the azure blob storage to decrease the upload time.
finally intention is to upload large files with short time.

Comment: Hi @arjunthota upload large files with short time as you said why you can't use [**Azure Data movement library**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-librar.y)?

Answer (score 0):

*Create a storage account and container in Azure*
[image]

*Create a container in storage account*
[image]

Using semaphore or threads we can upload blocks of file in azure

```
            string mystrconnectionString = "Connection String";
            string containerName = "container Name";
            var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(mystrconnectionString, containerName);
           string path = txtBrowsepath.Text;

            Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            try
            {
                BlobUploadOptions options = new BlobUploadOptions
                {
                    TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
                    {
                        MaximumConcurrency = 8,

                        MaximumTransferSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024
                    }
                };

                var tasks = new Queue<Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>>>();
               
                var blockBlob_Client = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("Sample.pdf");

                tasks.Enqueue(await blockBlob_Client.UploadAsync(path, options));

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                timer.Stop();
               MessageBox.Show("Uploaded files in {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} " timer +" seconds");
```

*Uploaded file in Azure in blocks*
[image]

*Checking File corrupted or not*
[image]

*Modified existing `.jpg` file to `.pdf` and file is checked whether it is corrupted or not, then it is showing as corrupted file- As expected.*

[image]

*Below is the code in to check the pdf file corrupted or not*

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(IsPDFCorrupted(txtBrowse.Text))
                { 
                    label2.Text = "File Not Corrupted!";
                }
                else
                {
                    label2.ForeColor= Color.Red;
                    label2.Text = "File Corrupted!";
                }
    
            }
            public bool IsPDFCorrupted(string fileName)
            {
                byte[] bf = null;
                FileStream file_stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file_stream);
                long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
                bf = br.ReadBytes(5);
    
                var enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
                var header = enc.GetString(bf);
    
                if (bf[0] == 0x25 && bf[1] == 0x50
                    && bf[2] == 0x44 && bf[3] == 0x46)
                {
                    return header.StartsWith("%PDF-");
                }
                return false;
            }
```